# Angular $http get works in browser but not on device - Ionic

Tags: javascript, angularjs, http, angularjs-scope, factory

I have a factory returning an object calling an internal resource containing JSON as so:

```
.factory('cardFactory', function ($q, $http) {
  return {
    getOtherStuff: function () {
      var deferred = $q.defer(),
        httpPromise = $http.get('/static/cards.json');

      httpPromise.then(function (response) {
        deferred.resolve(response);
      }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
    }
  };
});
```

In my controller I call it like this:

```
 var cardSuccess = function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.cards = data.data;
  };

  cardFactory.getOtherStuff()
    .then(cardSuccess, cardError);
```

In the browser $scope.cards in populated but on the device it doesn't populate.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm.., not sure.

I have it in a different way in my Ionic app, working great.

```
.factory('cardFactory', function ( $http ) {
    var promise;
      var cards = {
        getOtherStuff: function() {
          if ( !promise ) {
            // $http returns a promise, which has a then function, which also returns a promise
            promise = $http.get( '/static/cards.json' ).then(function (response) {
              // The then function here is an opportunity to modify the response
              // The return value gets picked up by the then in the controller.
              return response.data;
            });
          }
          return promise; // Return the promise to the controller
        }
      };
    return cards;
 })
```

Then, on the controller, calling it by:

```
$scope.getData = function() {

  // Call the async method and then do stuff with what is returned inside our own then function
  cardFactory.getOtherStuff().then(function(d) {
    $scope.cards= d;
  });
}
```

$scope.getData();

Hope it helps.

[EDIT:] Could it be the $http.get url, being relative? Have you tried with an absolute url?

Comment: As it works in the browser i presume its not a url prob, ill try this and let you know, thanks!

Comment: As much "promise" as that showed unfortunately it has the same issue. I think we both implemented basically the same thing in different ways. Still not sure what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

Replace $scope.cards=data.data with "$scope.cards=data"

```
var cardSuccess = function(data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.cards = data;
};
```

Comment: The cards are served fine in the browser so is'nt the issue, either way I tried it and unfortunately it doesn't work

Comment: Im testing on ios but i could test on android, isnt logcat a Java function? I am writing this in javascript, not sure i can log errors with it

Comment: logcat shows all logging n events, its build in eclipse.(http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-projects.html) You can try debugging yr app with weinre.(http://people.apache.org/~pmuellr/weinre-docs/latest/Home.html)

Comment: Ive developed in android before so im familiar with logcat, as my app is packaged by ionic i dont think i can debug it through the normal way, looking into options now

Answer (score 0):

try removing the leading slash in your url for $http. Try using 'static/cards.json' instead of '/static/cards.json'

I actually had the same problem and this fixed it for me. Hope it helps!